# How do I make it so a two top level widgets can't be open simultaneously?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a top level widget that is created when a button is pressed. How do I make it so when that same button is pressed again, while the top level widget is still open it simply moves the  top level widget into focus?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have the following method in a class. This method is called when you press the button. You will also have an instance attribute defined in the `__init__` method: `self.toplevel = None`.

```
def button_press(self):
    if self.toplevel is None:
        self.toplevel = ... # another method to create toplevel widget
    else:
        # set focus to self.toplevel
        # you can use self.toplevel.deiconify() if self.toplevel is minimised
        # also look at self.toplevel.lift() to bring the window to the top
```

You will also need to reset `self.toplevel` to `None` when the toplevel widget is destroyed.

Also look at the `focus_set` method of widgets. You may have to set the `take_focus` attribute to `True` for a toplevel widget. But maybe you want to set the focus to a particular widget (eg a Textbox) on the toplevel widget.

Comment: I would remove the "else". Simply create it if it doesn't exist then always raise it and give it focus.